# EntityState.Modified not working in Entity Code First

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dbcontext

I Use this code for update one field in my table.( with Entity Framework 6.1.3)

```
var model = new MyTable { Id = Id, UpdateTime = DateTime.UtcNow };
var dbSet = this.dbContext.Set<MyTable>();
dbSet.Attach(model);                
entry = this.dbContext.Entry(model);
entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
this.dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

but this not work and UpdateTime does not change.and when i change code to this:

```
var model = this.dbContext.Set<MyTable>().Find(id);
model = new MyTable { Id = Id, UpdateTime = DateTime.UtcNow };
var dbSet = this.dbContext.Set<MyTable>();              
entry = this.dbContext.Entry(model);
entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
this.dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

I found that in my first code , EF look to UpdateTime field that did not change, but is this right when i write:

```
entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
```

ef must generate update code , then why it does not?
How must i do for solve this problem?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think it might be because the Entry() call gets you an DbEntityEntry<TEntity>, while the DbSet is an IQueryable<TEntity>, so the returned entry is no longer part of the context.

Comment: no.it isn't.in DbSet<TEntity> summary wrote:
Returns a System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1 instance for access to entities of the given type in the context and the underlying store.
Note that Entity Framework requires that this method return the same instance  each time that it is called for a given context instance and entity type.
and this can be test with change dbSet variable with
this.dbContext.Set<MyTable>();
and result is same as before.

Comment: however, is exactly this entry the one that is attached to the context? I wouldn't be too sure about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally i found what's the problem?
I have a required string field in my table , and i found that we need to fill reference type fileds in Entity framework , and it can not be empty or whitespace character but not required the right value, and in this state we must don't use 
    entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
and instead of it we must use 
    entry.Property("UpdateTime").IsModified = true;
therefore this problem can be solved by this way:

```
var model = new MyTable { Id = Id, UpdateTime = DateTime.UtcNow , Title = "EveryThing" };
var dbSet = this.dbContext.Set<MyTable>();
dbSet.Attach(model);                
entry = this.dbContext.Entry(model);
entry.Property("UpdateTime").IsModified = true;
this.dbContext.SaveChanges();
```